# City load According Country wise In magento2

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout, magento-2.2.5, shipping-address

I want to city load on the checkout page when customer Select Country / State then City load accordingly, So anyone has the best idea how to do this or any extension have like this, please suggest me!